# Wordpress static first page for "Tags"

Tags: wordpress

I have a Wordpress site with a few dozen popular tag pages. I would like specific tag pages to reference the same post as the first result when someone visits a tag. Is this possible?

An example is if someone visits: www.domain.com/tag/TAGONE/

There are about 20 posts that appear. I would like one specific post to appear first.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Tag Sticky Post` plugin might be what you're looking for:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/tag-sticky-post/

Comment: THANK YOU! That is exactly what I have been searching for!! Much appreciated.